# Shift incremental data from s3 to redshift

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a csv file that gets updated frequently. I have to move data from this csv file to Redshift as and when a new entry is encountered.

I have created an event in s3 to invoke a Lambda function whenever a PUT operation takes place. This Lambda function runs a Glue job which is responsible for shifting the data.

When I put some data in s3, I am not able to see any addition in the Redshift table. What can be the issue?

Comment: Did it trigger the Glue job? Did the Glue job give any errors? You could also consider using [A Zero-Administration Amazon Redshift Database Loader | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/a-zero-administration-amazon-redshift-database-loader/) or [S3 to RedShift loader](http://g14n.info/2016/04/s3-to-redshift-loader/).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The glue job ran successfully.

Comment: If the glue job ran successfully, then the data should be in Redshift. You might want to look more closely at what the Glue job is doing.

Comment: you might want to consider using redshift spectrum for this,

Comment: You can check `stl_load_commits` view in redshift to see what did the glue job exactly do.